# Preinstalled audio, photo and video data size

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, data

Have recently purchased new MacBook Pro 13″ 2015 (128 GB) and noticed that "About my Mac" displays 1.31 Gb Audio, 750 Mb photo and 410 Mb Films. Does it mean that someone else stored this data on the notebook or it's preinstalled data by the manufacturer?

Answer (score 3):

It could quite easily be Garage Band, if not other app data too. My Garage Band folder at `/Library/Application Support/GarageBand` is actually 4.8 GB

Source: [Delete GarageBand to Save Precious Gigabytes of Mac Storage](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/delete-garageband/)

> As a rich media application, GarageBand installs relatively large groups of media files to several locations on your Mac’s drive. Based on a clean install of GarageBand 10.0.2 on OS X 10.9.3, key locations of large files include:
>
> `/Applications/GarageBand.app` (1.16GB)
>   `/Library/Application Support/GarageBand` (995MB)
>   `/Library/Application Support/Logic` (880MB)
>   `/Library/Audio/Apple Loops` (up to 10GB)*
>
> *Note that the size of the Apple Loops directory will vary depending on the number and type of loops downloaded by the user. You should not delete this folder (or the Logic folder) if you are using Logic Pro.
>
> Under normal circumstances, however, users looking to delete GarageBand can expect to save around 3GB of space. It may not seem like much, especially as storage capacities continue to rise, but 3GB can make a huge difference for those with small SSDs.

Comment: Looks like it's true. Thank you. Could I delete this software and then istall it from AppStore if I need?

Comment: I'd check in your 'Purchased' list in the App Store first, just to make sure it shows up in there. If it does, then yes; if not, then you'd possibly have to repurchase it - I'm not quite sure how it goes for bundled apps.

Answer (score 0):

Not having a fresh out-of-the-box MacBook on hand, I can only assume it's data from apps like iMovie or Garageband or Pages and Keynote. OS X could be computing the data those apps have as photos and audio and video. Background images might also be included.

Comment: Yes, maybe. But 1.31 Gb Audio is too much, I think, but could be wrong, of course.

Comment: @LightGuard Did you look at what the files actually were?

Comment: There are a lot of sound effects and audio clips that iMovie and Garageband have that are of high quality I believe. I could still be wrong of course. Only way to know is to find out where the audio files are. Sorry I wasn't more helpful.

Comment: @tubedogg, I've triend but can't find it. Should I turn on hidden files display to check it out or login by root?

Comment: Use something like [DaisyDisk](http://daisydiskapp.com/) to show you what folders are using the space.

Comment: @thepoch, thank you. Looks like it's really software libraries, etc. ;)

Comment: @tubedogg, thank you. Downloaded DaisyDisk and it shows software and it's libraries. Great app. :)