# Apple Sierra deleted GarageBand still taking up 1.76G of space!

Tags: mac, macos, garageband

I have followed all of the other thread suggestions to remove the majority of GarageBand files from my MacBook Air ([How to completely remove Garage Band from macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252306/how-to-completely-remove-garage-band-from-macos)), short of reinstalling the app and using a third-party app uninstaller to do a sweep. I'm at a loss as to where this +1G of space is being hogged.

[image]

I never "bought" the app, it was already installed when I bought my laptop. I do not use GarageBand or any related app (Logic).

I have emptied the /Audio and /Audio Loop folders. I have deleted all Receipts. I have even used Terminal to find any mention of GarageBand, which only came up with 4 very small files stored in the /PrivateFrameworks folder which cannot be deleted.

What else can I do to get my 1.76G of space back? I couldn't care less if it was on my desktop Mac, but my portable workspace needs all the storage space I can give it, and I hate having it wasted on something I do not nor never will use!

Thanks for any additional input you can give on this.

Comment: Have you looked in `Macintosh HD/Library/Application Support/Garage Band`? My folder has 11GB of files in it.

Comment: I've seen you fixed it - but check this link for where GB puts files, make sure they're all clean - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182491/preinstalled-audio-photo-and-video-data-size/182494#182494

Comment: Yup! All clean. Absolutely ZERO GB files left. For some reason, even though the numbers updated for other things as I cleaned up my drive, those for GB did not until I restarted my computer. When in doubt, restart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so.... after posting this, on a whim I decided restarting my laptop to see if that purged anything extra, even though it was still showing the 1.76G being used. I didn't think it would make any difference, but I suddenly remembered that was always worth a try when dealing with things like this.

Gonna answer my own question by saying, once you've actually followed the above linked-thread, **restart your computer**!

Storage Management now shows **Zero KB** of space being used for "Music Creation". GarageBand is no longer the space hog it was. Huzzah!